# Banking System Project [beginner] basic errors

Tags: c++, visual-c++

This is a file for my project. I cannot figure why I am getting three errors on a bracket.
For the record, I have made numerous attempts to fix this prior to posting a question on here. I have just been working on it for so long that I was simply overlooking what was wrong. Now that another set of eyes have flashed a red light on what was wrong, I now feel stupid for asking. I just refuse to take a break from working on this until I finish it. But, again thanks for everyone's input and help. 
Errors:

Errors:

```
----\bankingsystem.h(45) : error C2236: unexpected 'class' 'BankingSystem'. Did you forget a ';'?`
----\bankingsystem.h(45) : error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '{'`
----\bankingsystem.h(45) : error C2447: '{' : missing function header (old-style formal list?)`
---\bankingsystem.h(72) : fatal error C1020: unexpected #endif`
```

```
#ifndef BANKING_SYSTEM_H
#define BANKING_SYSTEM_H

#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <string> // Used to allow string functions

using namespace std;


class Account {

public:
Account( int accountNumberValue, int passCode, string lastName, string firstName, double balance);
~Account();

void setFirstName ( string & );
string getFirstName();

void setLastName( string & );
string getLastName();

void setAccountNumber( int accountNumberValue );
int getAccountNumber();

void setPassCode( int passCodeValue );
int getPassCode();

void setBalance( double balanceValue );
double getBalance();


private:
string firstName;
string lastName;
int accountNumber;
int passCode;
double balance;

} // end class Account

#endif // Account_h

class BankingSystem
{ ---(45)
public:
BankingSystem();
~BankingSystem();

void addAccount();//option 1
Account query(int accountId);

void deleteAccount();//option 2
Account query(int accountId);

void AccountInquiry();//option 3
Account query(int accountId);

void saveAccount();//option 4
Account query(int accountId);

void loadAccounts();//option 5
Account query(int accountId);


private:
vector<Account> accounts_;

};



#endif ----(72)
```

I marked where the errors are occurring, lines (45) and (72).

By no means am I asking for anyone to debug my program, I am just asking for an explanation on why these errors are occurring.

1. Why is there an unexpected class?
2. How is there a syntax error?

Comment: As the message implies, you forgot a `;`.  Class definitions should be postfixed with a `;`.  e.g. `class Foo { ... };`.

Comment: You also have `Account query(int accountId);` repeated several times in `BankingSystem` which is not valid and you have two `#endif` one after each class definition.

Comment: Class Account { ... }; you missing the ;

Comment: You should not have written this much code before testing it, and you should have reduced it to a minimal example before asking us to examine it.

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out in the comments:

- Unexpected class is because you haven't marked the current `Account` class as finished using `;` after the closing curly brace `}`
- You have two `#endif` for single `#ifndef`
- And multiple declaration of `Account query(int accountId);`

Here is the fixed code:

```
#ifndef BANKING_SYSTEM_H
#define BANKING_SYSTEM_H

#include <string> // Used to allow string functions
#include <vector>

class Account {
public:
  Account( int accountNumberValue, int passCode, std::string lastName, 
           std::string firstName, double balance);
  ~Account();

  void setFirstName ( std::string & );
  std::string getFirstName();

  void setLastName( std::string & );
  std::string getLastName();

  void setAccountNumber( int accountNumberValue );
  int getAccountNumber();

  void setPassCode( int passCodeValue );
  int getPassCode();

  void setBalance( double balanceValue );
  double getBalance();


private:
  std::string firstName;
  std::string lastName;
  int accountNumber;
  int passCode;
  double balance;

}; // end class Account

class BankingSystem
{
public:
  BankingSystem();
  ~BankingSystem();

  Account query(int accountId);

  void addAccount();//option 1

  void deleteAccount();//option 2

  void AccountInquiry();//option 3

  void saveAccount();//option 4

  void loadAccounts();//option 5

private:
  std::vector<Account> accounts_;
};

#endif // BANKING_SYSTEM_H
```

Comment: Thanks a bunch for everyone's help. I have been working on this all day and I just couldn't see what I was missing.. I really appreciate everyone's help.